# uncomment and comment button in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

How can I show these buttons please? They are usually there in C# but not in R. I can use of course CTRL+E, U and CTRL+E, C. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Tools menu, select Customize. In the dialog that opens, select the Commands tab. Select Toolbar radio button and in the dropdown next to it select the toolbar you wish to add the buttons to. Or go to the Toolbars tab and create a new one, select it, then back to Commands tab and select the new toolbar.
Click on Add Command..., select the Edit category and then scroll through the long list of commands until you find "Selection Comment" and Selection Uncomment" and add them to your toolbar.

Answer (score 5):

They are in the Text Editor toolbar.

View --> Toolbars --> Text Editor

Answer (score 0):

My new installs or updated versions of VS sometimes seems to not remember my personal preferences, so I've had this same question, as well. The default key commands work, but sometimes the new VS does not show the toolbars that include the comment/uncomment buttons for all the file types in which I want them to show.
To add the buttons, open a file you are not seeing the tabs for, click View => Toolbars, and make sure Text Editor is selected.
Or, right-click on some open tab space at the top of your VS screen, and click "Customize". The resulting window should show plenty of Toolbars in the Toolbars tab. Make sure the "Text Editor" is selected - that's where the comment/uncomment buttons reside.

This should be the case for Visual Studio 2015-2017

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for comment and uncomment buttons in visual studio 2019, I am posting here...

You can do it in two ways

1. Right click on any free space in the Visual Studio toolbar, then select “Text Editor”. comment and uncomment buttons will appear.
2. Go to view -> toolsbar -> texteditor then you can see comment and uncomment buttons.